# Pandas fails to filter empty groups with DataFrameGroupBy.filter

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I group a dataframe with a datetime index into 10 minutes bucket. I want then to check the length of each bucket and discard buckets with a number of elements lower than the maximum one.

Groupby, however, keeps creating an empty group that does not contain any element and that, therefore, is not removed.

Look at the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

"Generate test dataframe"
rng = pd.date_range('2018-11-26 16:17:43.510000', periods=90000, freq='0.04S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(len(rng)),'b':np.random.randn(len(rng))}, index=rng)

"Set interval and start time of the buckets"
interval = dt.timedelta(minutes=10)
t0 = df.index[0]
base = t0.minute + (t0.second +t0.microsecond/1e6)/60

"Group df"
groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=interval, base=base))

print(len(groups)) 
#7

print(groups.size())

#2018-11-26 16:17:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:27:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:37:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:47:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:57:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 17:07:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 17:17:43.510        0 <- I want to remove this group

"Remove all buckets with a lower number of samples"
maxSize = max(groups.size())
def ismaxlen(x):
    print(len(x) == maxSize)
    return len(x) == maxSize

df = groups.filter(ismaxlen) #Prints 6 times True and one time False
                             #This should have removed the last group!
"Group again data"
groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=interval, base=base))

print(len(groups)) 
#Prints again 7!! The 7th ghost group is still there

print(groups.size())

#2018-11-26 16:17:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:27:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:37:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:47:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 16:57:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 17:07:43.510    15000
#2018-11-26 17:17:43.510        0  <- This group is still here



#Some more weirdness...

print(groups.groups)

#{Timestamp('2018-11-26 16:17:43.510000'): 15000,
# Timestamp('2018-11-26 16:27:43.510000'): 30000,
# Timestamp('2018-11-26 16:37:43.510000'): 45000,
# Timestamp('2018-11-26 16:47:43.510000'): 60000,
# Timestamp('2018-11-26 16:57:43.510000'): 75000,
# Timestamp('2018-11-26 17:07:43.510000'): 90000, <-
# Timestamp('2018-11-26 17:17:43.510000'): 90000} <-last two groups ends at the same index!

print(df.index[-1])
#2018-11-26 17:17:43.470000
# Last data has an index < than last group. Last group should not even exist! 
#Why is a group starting at 17:43.51 created if the last sample is at 17:43.470000

print(len(groups.indices)) 
#Prints 6. I have 7 groups, but only 6 indices! 7th group doesn't even exist!
```

How can I avoid this behaviour? Why is this happening? Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the output you are getting, and your expected output?

Comment: Added outputs and more comments. The expected output should be clear: a groupby object with **SIX** groups and **NOT SEVEN**

Comment: Odd I just tested the code [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php) and got the expected output specifically in line 17 im getting 6 groups and not 7

Comment: Holy Crap! This is weird! And even more weird, I'm running pandas version 0.23.4, while codinground has version 0.20.1

Comment: So you are getting the expected output also using that compiler?

Comment: Yes, but not with this one for example https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6, Pandas version 0.23.4

Comment: Also this compiler returns the wrong output https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187898/discussion-between-edeki-okoh-and-luca-amerio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the `base` option. Depending on the value of `base`, groupby fails to create the correct number of groups.

Since the last group does't have members, `filter` does not remove anything and the second groupby simply repeat exactly what the first did.

The issue only happens in Python 3 with pandas version < 0.24.

This can be reproduced doing

```
"Generate test dataframe"
case = 1
if case == 1:
    start = '2018-11-26 16:17:43.510000'
else:
    start = '2018-11-26 16:17:43.500000'

rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10, freq='1S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(len(rng)),'b':np.random.randn(len(rng))}, index=rng)

"Set interval and start time of the buckets"
interval = dt.timedelta(minutes=10)
t0 = df.index[0]
base = t0.minute + (t0.second +t0.microsecond/1e6)/60
groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=interval, base=base))

print(groups.size())
```

This generates 2 groups (one of which empty) in case1, but only 1 in case2.

This has been solved in pandas 0.24 and is discussed here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25161